# Read Discord channel messages with a bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am developing a python bot to read all incomming messages that I received on my account. The code is quite simple:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content
    print(messageContent)
                      
client.run('tokengoeshere')
```

However, it only works if i add it to a server which i manage.

Is there any way to read messages of a channel if i'm on it but i don't have permissions to add the bot?

Comment: Not possible, I think it pretty much makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know there is no way to read a channel with a bot if the bot isn't in the server because it doesn't have any permissions on that server